# Loop items with higher click_count first

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript

I am making a recent search results component. In this component im taking search results from the API, and there is a value called "click_count". Every time someone get a positive result from the recent search that was clicked this value will increase by one.

Now I want to show the ones with the highest click_count first. Anyone knows how this is possible?

HTML

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let recent of searchSrvc.displayRecents | slice:0:5; let i=index">
    <div class="result-row-wrapper">
      <div class="icon-row-wrapper recents">
        <ng-container>
          <i class="fas fa-clock" (click)="setRecent(recent)"></i>
          <p class="label" (click)="setRecent(recent)">{{ recent.search_text }}</p>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="recent.user_id === this.model.id">
          <i class="own-search fas fa-times" (click)="deleteSearch(i)"></i>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
    </ng-container>
```

TS

```
The typescript just consists of an array im calling with multiple items that look like this:
{
archived: "0"
atime: null
auser: null
click_count: "0"
ctime: "1633514604"
cuser: "Dev Gebruiker"
id: "7"
mtime: "1633514604"
muser: "Dev Gebruiker"
organisation_id: "31"
resource: "building"
results_count: "0"
search_text: "add e"
ucurrency: "EUR"
user_id: "1"
},
```

Comment: do you have a post api to keep the count, you cannot count clicks just from the javascript UI code, you need an API and db to store the click count

Answer (score 0):

Changing the order of items in an array is called *sorting*. The `Array` prototype already contains a method to sort, [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```
const sortedArray = [...array].sort((a, b) => {
  return Number(b.click_count) - Number(a.click_count)
})
```

Now use this `sortedArray` in your template with a regular `*ngFor`.